# How to use Excluding in FluentAssertions to exclude specific KeyValue pair in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, fluent-assertions

I'm using FluentAssertions with `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` to compare two dictionaries of type `Dictionary<string, string>` but want to exclude one or more specific KeyValue pairs (because they contain timestamps in this case). How to do this?

I tried things like: `opt => opt.Excluding(x => x.Single(kv => kv.Key == "MySearchKey"))` but this results in errors like: `Message: System.ArgumentException : Expression <Convert(x.Single(kv => (kv.Key == "MySearchKey")))> cannot be used to select a member.`

Is what I want possible? Or should I maybe exclude the value only and not the pair (that's maybe even better because the existence of the key will be checked then)? Thanks!

Comment: Why not exclude the key value pair with linq Exclude and the compare the results

Comment: @Nkosi, thanks for the suggestion, I'm using a similar filtering method (as suggested by Jonas below) now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Excluding()` is meant to exclude members of a *type*, not excluding a member of a *collection*, see [documentation](http://fluentassertions.com/documentation.html#selecting-members) for more info.

Note: the code below is for the current stable version 4.19.4 of Fluent Assertions.

Example: 
You want to compare instances of `Person` and `PersonDTO`, but `Person` contains the `AnotherProperty` which you want to exclude from the object comparison.

```
var person = new Person
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "McClane",
    AnotherProperty = 42
};

var personDTO = new PersonDTO
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "McClane"
};
```

This is where you would use `Exclude` to exclude a member of a type.

```
person.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(personDTO, options => options.Excluding(e => e.AnotherProperty));
```

In your concrete case I would not use `ShouldBeEquivalentTo`.
Consider these two dictionary instances, where you want to omit a member of a *collection*, here the member with `Key == "unknown"`.

```
var actual = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    ["one"] = 1,
    ["two"] = 2,
    ["three"] = 3,
    ["unknown"] = -1,
    ["fail"] = -2
};

var expected = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    ["one"] = 1,
    ["two"] = 2,
    ["three"] = 3
};
```

You could either just filter out the unwanted key-value pairs:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> filtered = actual.Where(e => e.Key != "unknown");
```

Now the assertion will be between two `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`s

```
filtered.Should().Equal(expected);
```

which will give the following assertion failure message:

```
FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionFailedException: 'Expected collection to be equal to {[one, 1], [two, 2], [three, 3]}, but {[one, 1], [two, 2], [three, 3], [fail, -2]} contains 1 item(s) too many.'
```

Otherwise turn the filtered enumerable back into a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, int> filteredDict = actual.Where(e => e.Key != "unknown")
    .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
```

You will now be comparing `Dictionary<string, int>`s again:

```
filteredDict.Should().Equal(expected);
```

which will give the following assertion failure message:

```
FluentAssertions.Execution.AssertionFailedException: 'Expected dictionary to be equal to {[one, 1], [two, 2], [three, 3]}, but found additional keys {"fail"}.'
```

If want to use the second approach and you do this often, you could create extension methods to extract the logic of removing a member from the test method.

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> ExceptKeys<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, params TKey[] keys)
    {
        if (dictionary == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dictionary));
        if (keys == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keys));

        return dictionary.Where(e => !keys.Contains(e.Key)).ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
    }

    public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> ExceptValues<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, params TValue[] values)
    {
        if (dictionary == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dictionary));
        if (values == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));

        return dictionary.Where(e => !values.Contains(e.Value)).ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
    }
}
```

You can now write an in my opinion more clear and concise test:

```
actual.ExceptKeys("unknown").Should().Equal(expected);
```

Comment: Jonas, thanks for your very thorough explanation! I was used to ShouldBeEquivalentTo because I compared objects with objects most of the time. Should().Equal() is indeed much better when comparing dictionaries. I also switched to your filtering solution. Nice approach and it suits my needs perfectly. So thanks again!

Comment: Beware that ExceptKeys and ExceptValues should be used with care since they don't preserve the equality comparer of the dictionary keys of the original dictionary.